# Setting a rule based on the action of checking and THEN unchecking a box

Tags: infopath

I have a form where certain checkboxes are assigned a points system.

Example:

> if field 1=True add 1 point to "points Total" field, subtract a point
>   if Field 2=true.

I have the rules set up for that situation, but I run into a problem where a user can check a box (thus adding the point) and if he unchecks the same box, that point remains. He can then keep adding points by re-clicking that box.

Is there a rule that can say "if field 1 goes from "false" to "true" add 1 point but if field 1 goes from "True" to "false", subtract 1 point.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add two rules for the same checkbox for checked and unchecked. Increment if checked and subtract if unchecked.

Here Title is the checkbox and Year is the field you want to increment or decrement.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that make the default value of it being unchecked as a -1?

Comment: Check the value of the field to be greater than 0 before you decrement it

Comment: I'm fairly new at this. Can you give me a brief example of how to check the field and then decrement it? Would that be an "IF" formula?

Comment: Updated my answer